# Generating a MSS file at command-line?

Tags: xilinx, microblaze

Is there a way to generate a mss file from the exported SDK XML file at command-line? At the moment, I still have to open xsdk, generate a new hello world project to create the mss file. But I would like to generate the mss file with makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Xilinx tool `appguru` to generate an MSS file from the exported XML file

```
appguru -hw proc.xml -app empty_application
```

See `appguru -h` for help

Answer (score 1):

This thread on the Xilinx forums appears to have what you need:

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/Creating-files-for-libgen-mss-and-maybe-others-from-Console/m-p/272726/highlight/true#M24815

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've seen that one.  It's probably working but I fear it will not be stable across different versions of the Xilinx tools.  I'm still surprised there is no Xilinx command to generate those MSS files.